# RcppRoll Window Opening

Tags: r, rcpp, rolling-sum

I've been using the RcppRoll package to do rolling sums, but I'd like to find a function/option that would allow me to turn a vector like this    `[1 2 3 4 5]` into    `[1 3 6 9 12]` for a window of 3, for instance.

Currently, I've been using roll_sum, which returns
    `[NA NA 6 9 12]` for a window of 3.

It seems like it would work to use something like `rollapplyr(x, 3, sum, partial=TRUE)`, but that's just far too slow for something I'll eventually need to run on millions of rows.

Comment: [edit] the question and show some code. See [ask].

Answer (score 4):

Insert zeros at the beginning of the input:

```
width <- 3
roll_sum(c(numeric(width-1), 1:5), width)
## [1]  1  3  6  9 12
```